# Is there a reason my browser percent decodes a uri?

Tags: http, urlencode

When I type the following into Firefox or Chrome:

```
http://localhost:50102/my%2Ftest/one
```

... and I look at the request header, it shows:

```
http://localhost:50102/my/test/one
```

Why would it do this?

Comment: To encode a %, use %25. So, `http://localhost:50102/my%252Ftest/one`

Comment: @TomBlodget took me a min to soak that in, but you have a point. If need to send % in request header, that works. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because it’s meant to do exactly that. The `%` introduces a two-digit hex number that is taken as a single character. 0x2F happens to be `/` in ASCII. To encode a space, you’d use `%20`.

Comment: does this mean percent encoding cannot be used in the path? one the server side, what happens if it needs to read a reserved character of a slash in a certain spot without altering the path?

Comment: As far as HTTP goes, everything that comes after the host part is sent to the server to handle. There is no concept of path and sub-path or such. The interpretation of slashes is outside the scope of the specification. If you want to follow the common notion that the slash separates path segments and still allow path segments to contain slashes, you have to make up your own encoding. You could let the server handle double-slashes in a special way, for instance.